# How to access indexes of a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I am give a list of dictionaries, where

```
dict1 = dict(a = 2, b = 5, c = 7)
dict2 = dict(c = 5, d = 5, e = 1)
dict3 = dict(e = 2, f = 4, g = 10)
list_of_dictionaries = [dict1, dict2, dict3]
```

How would I be able to, find the value of the highest index (aka the latest dictionary)?

So if I were to write a method to delete an item from the list of dictionaries, let's say I want to delete `c` from the dictionary.

How would I be able to delete the c from the second dictionary instead of the first?

Comment: For starters your definition of the dictionaries would fail.

Comment: Sorry about that! Fixed.

Comment: You could have also "fixed" it by just removing the "python" tag.

Comment: also to build a python dictionary it should be: `dict1 = dict(a = 2, b = 5, c = 7)`, or `dict1 = {'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 7}`

Answer (score 1):

The key is reversing through the list with reverse indexing (`a_list[::-1]`).
From there once you find any dictionary that matches the requirements alter it and quit the function or loop - hence the early `return`s.

This code:

```
def get_last(bucket,key):
  for d in bucket[::-1]:
    if key in d.keys():
      return d[key]
  return None

def set_last(bucket,key,val):
  for d in bucket[::-1]:
    if key in d.keys():
       d[key] = val
       return

def pop_last(bucket,key):
  out = None
  for d in bucket[::-1]:
    if key in d.keys():
      return d.pop(key)

dict1 = {'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 7}
dict2 = {'c': 5, 'd': 5, 'e': 1}
dict3 = {'e': 2, 'f': 4, 'g': 10}
list_of_dictionaries = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

print get_last(list_of_dictionaries ,'c')
set_last(list_of_dictionaries ,'c',7)
print list_of_dictionaries 
popped = pop_last(list_of_dictionaries ,'c')
print popped
print list_of_dictionaries
```

Gives:

```
5
[{'a': 2, 'c': 7, 'b': 5}, {'c': 7, 'e': 1, 'd': 5}, {'e': 2, 'g': 10, 'f': 4}]
7
[{'a': 2, 'c': 7, 'b': 5}, {'e': 1, 'd': 5}, {'e': 2, 'g': 10, 'f': 4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean but I wan to show you a couple of things that might help:

First here is how your dictionaries should look like:

```
dict1 = {"a" :2, "b" : 5, "c" :7}
dict2 = {"c" :5, "d" :5, "e" :1}
dict3 = {"e" :2, "f" :4, "g" :10}
```

Then you asked this: *"How would I be able to delete the c from the second dictionary instead of the first?"*

You can do delete it this way:

```
del dict2["c"]
```